# Windows, batch, git automatic commit, pull, push, telling it to my private key

Tags: git, batch-file, github

I have this:

```
C:
cd c:/my/project/path
git add .
git pull
git commit -am "."
git push
PAUSE
```

this seems to work until I want to pull the repo. Then it needs my login/password. I have the private key file, how to tell it where is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check:

- if you are using an ssh url (`git@github.com:<user>/<repo>`): see the output of `git remote -v` (or, since git 2.7, `git remote get-url origin`)
- if you have set the environment variable `HOME` (generally to `%USERPROFILE%`), as git will look for the public and private ssh keys in `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`

Comment: gut remote -v returns:

origin  *@*.git (fetch)
origin  *@*.git (push)

but I have no idea what to do with this. The %userprofile% is SET but doesnt seems like GIT is looking for key there

Comment: @JohnSmith first, in your script, add `set HOME=%USERPROFILE%`. I know that `%USERPROFILE%` is set (that is what Windows use). But you need to set HOME as well.

Comment: @JohnSmith Second, set your remote url correctly. cd into your repo and type `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<user>/<repo>` (replace user and repo with your GitHub user and your GitHub repo name)

Comment: oh yea sorry, I didnt double-check it. Now it seems to work